# Spring Gateway Service failed due to Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I've added keycloak to my API Gateway and since then its failed to startup, more specifically after adding tokenRelay as default-filter, here's the log

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay
```

I've declared all necessary dependencies

- jose
- resource server
- oauth2 client
- starter-security

and my application class has eureka enabled and consuming properties from the config server.

I'm using boot version: 2.3.12.RELEASE, cloud: Hoxton.RELEASE, java 8

I've added in application.yml

```
...
    default-filters:
       - TokenRelay
```

Comment: Please add the versions you are using

Comment: @spencergibb added to my question, thanks!

Comment: Token relay is part of spring cloud security for hoxton. 2020.0.3 it is part of gateway

Comment: Thanks for the information, I've tried updating the versions but still the same.

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: @spencergibb I've just resolved the problem by adding the spring-cloud-security, Truly it's weird, I went through GitHub issues and found that TokenRelay was deprecated specifically for one version, I cant' remember exactly. However, I appreciate your time. Thank you!

Comment: that would be the solution for hoxton, it is not needed in 2020.0.x